# QListWidget Align Items Center

Tags: pyqt, center, alignment, qlistwidget, qlist

I am adding a list of strings to a QList Widget like this:

```
myList.addItems( [ 'item1' , 'item2' , 'item3' ] )
```

By default the list aligns these to the left but I want to get them in the center of the list.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create a `QListWidgetItem()` you can call its `setTextAlignment()` method and pass `Qt.AlignHCenter`:

```
item_text_list = [ 'item1' , 'item2' , 'item3' ]

for item_text in item_text_list:
    item = QListWidgetItem(item_text)
    item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
    myList.addItem(item)
```

Docs:
[QListWidgetItem](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlistwidgetitem.html), [Qt.AlignmentFlag](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qt.html#AlignmentFlag-enum)